# Tengo problemas con la el hasheo de la contraseña en php

Tags: php, poo, pdo, login

he creado un login donde al guardar el usuario y su contraseña se hashea y se encripta a la bd pero cuando intento poner la contraseña de forma "normal" no me ingresa porque no está en forma encriptada, en cambio si pongo el usuario y la contraseña  en la forma encripatada copiando desde la bd recién me ingresa el usuario, si pueden ayudarme a solucionarlo les agredecería bastante, les dejo mi código abajo.
https://github.com/frankpezo/Bora_ejemplo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so]. Recuerda realizar el [tour] y revisar [ask]. Recuerda que el código no va como imagen sino como texto

Comment: Como dijo Pipe, es mejor cuando el código está como texto, [formateado](/help/formatting). Lectura recomendada: [un fragmento de código vale más que mil imagenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/158880)

Answer (score -2):

El error que tienes esta en la llamada a login... estas enviando la contraseña sin encriptar y la comparas con la contraseña encriptada en db, solo corrige la siguiente linea:

```
33    $login = $usuarioInsertado->login($usuario, $contraHash);
```

Espero que esto resuelva tu problema.

Te recomiendo que en futuros posts incluyas el codigo directamente y las referencias en lugar de imagenes.

Comment: Hola,  ya lo puse así y no, no funciona, me sigue botando error.

Comment: @FrankPezo Me resulta obvio que tienes un problema al comparar los valores y con tus respuestas sin informacion adicional o un dump de tus variables, es muy dificil tratar de seguir tu codigo, espero que alguien mas pueda ayudarte.